# malloc structure C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I can't understand why this litle code doesn't work ! i get it from [C struct and malloc problem (C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768582/c-struct-and-malloc-problem-c) (selected answer) and I wonder why it doesn't work for me.

any idea ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *leftChild;
    struct node *rightChild;
} node;

typedef struct tree {
    int numNodes;
    struct node** nodes;
} tree;

tree *initTree() {
   /* in C code (not C++), don't have to cast malloc's return pointer, it's implicitly converted from void* */
   tree* atree = malloc(sizeof(tree)); /* different names for variables */
   node* anode = malloc(sizeof(node));
   atree->nodes[0] = anode; // <-------- SEG FAULT HERE !
   return atree;
}

int main() {
    tree* mytree = initTree();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `atree->nodes` point to not allocated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a call to

```
tree* atree = malloc(sizeof(tree));
```

you have allocated a memory for `tree` object, so for a `struct node** nodes` pointer to (as it is a struct member), but it doesn't point to valid memory yet. You have to allocate also a memory for the `nodes` to which it is supposed to point to. For example:

```
atree->nodes = malloc( atree->numNodes*(sizeof (node*)));
```